# Django DETAIL: Failing row contains (11, SG 553, BATTLE-SCARRED, CLASSIFIED, NORMAL, RIFLE, null, 6235.05)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

task to create **Weapon** objects:

```
def populate_weapon_objects(amount: int = 1) -> None:
    for _ in range(amount):
        Weapon.objects.create(
            name=_get_random_name(),
            exterior=_get_random_exterior(),
            quality=_get_random_quality(),
            category=_get_random_category(),
            price=_get_random_price(),
        )
```

**Weapon** model:

```
class Weapon(models.Model):
     ...
    
     name = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=WEAPONS, db_index=True)
     exterior = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=EXTERIOR, default=EXTERIOR_FACTORY_NEW, db_index=True)
     quality = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=QUALITY, default=QUALITY_CONSUMER_GRADE, db_index=True)
     category = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=CATEGORY, default=CATEGORY_NORMAL, db_index=True)
     type = models.CharField(max_length=64, editable=False, db_index=True)
     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=64, editable=False, unique=True, db_index=True)
     price = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(10**4)], db_index=True)
     updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.type:
            self.type = self._get_type_by_name()
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self._get_slug()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

     def _get_type_by_name(self) -> str:
        return next(k for k, v in self.NAME_TO_TYPE_DICT.items() if self.name in v)
    
     def _get_slug(self) -> None:
        self.slug = generate_slug(self)
```

**generate_slug** function:

```
def generate_slug(weapon) -> str:
    name = weapon.name
    exterior = weapon.exterior
    quality = weapon.quality
    category = weapon.category
    sequence = [name, exterior, quality, category]
    slug = slugify(' '.join(sequence))
    return slug
```

This leads to:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "slug" of 
relation "weapons_weapon" violates not-null constraint
celery-worker  | DETAIL:  Failing row contains (14, PP-BIZON, 
MINIMAL WEAR, RESTRICTED, NORMAL, SMG, null, 7354.3, 
2022-09-15 13:15:43.75499+00, 2022-09-15 13:15:43.754978+00).
```

Why this happens? Why the **type** field is being filled when creating an **Weapon** objects and **slug** field keeps crashing (not being filled)? Please Help.

Doesn't the `create()` method call `save()` method of an object? I am clearly sure it does. But why then **self.type** gets a value and **self.slug** does not?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It was in **_get_slug** method

```
def _get_slug(self) -> None:
    self.slug = generate_slug(self)
```

It was returning **NoneType** + it was already trying to assign value to **slug** field. Why I say 'was trying' is because then in `save` method it was again assigning the **return** value of **_get_slug** method which is **None**:

```
if not self.slug:
    self.slug = self._get_slug() # returns None
```

I changed my code to:

```
def _get_slug(self) -> str:
    return generate_slug(self)
```

Now it works perfectly.